# Managing multiple UITextField in a single UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uitextfield

I have more than one `UITextField`'s in single `UITableviewCell`.
I know we can identify `subviews` of `UITableViewCell` with using tags.
But in my scenario I have multiple `UITextField` in single `UITableViewCell`.

How can I provide tag to identify which `UITextField` is clicked?

Comment: Tags per UITextfields, then you can compare row=1, tag=1 etc.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya:Thanks for replying but I have multiple textfield in single UITableViewCell.

Comment: Yes, why cant you have tags/identifiers for each of them?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya:Can you please elaborate in detail?

Comment: you can use custom protocol and delegate method

Comment: UITextFields are static or dynamically created at run time? and Also, How many cells having in tableview?

Comment: You can create a composite tag. For example if you have four textfields in each row then, the tags for fields in first row would be -

00 - 01 - 02 - 03 - First Row
10 - 11 - 12 - 13 - Second Row and so on.

Answer (score 1):

When you have multiple `UITextFeild's` in your `UITableViewCell`, give tag to each of the `textfield` in your `cellForRowAtIndex` method. And then when you tap on the `textfield`, the `UITextFieldDelegate` will get hit.

For example,`textFieldShouldBeginEditing` will get hit when you tap on a `textfield`.

Or, you can even add Observers to your textfield, and then you can simply validate which textfield is tapped.

If you consider the delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   if(textfield.tag==1)
   {
      //you tapped textfield 1
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, since you have more than one textField in each Cell, simply using the row as tag will still be impossible to distinguish between which textField it is from that specific row.

What I usually do in these scenarios is to encode 2 values in the tag.

For example you can save it like this:

```
textField.tag = indexPath.row * 1000 + TEXTFIELD_INDEX
```

and then, on a delegate method for that textField you would retrieve it like:

```
NSInteger textFieldIndex = textField.tag % 1000;
NSInteger row = textField.tag / 1000;
```

The textField index will be stored as the remainder of 1000 on the tag, and the row itself will be stored as the thousands.

**Note:** There's an implicit limitation when doing this, in which you can only have up to 1000 textFields in each cell, and about 2000000 cells. Assuming tag is a 32 bit integer. But I find that pretty reasonable :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the tag in storyboard or nib files.

Select the textfield, select the properties tab on the right, modify tag in the View section.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a tag like

```
 cell.contentView.subviews.enumerated().forEach { (offset, view) in
    (view as! UITextField).tag = 100 + offset 
 }
```

Then in

```
extension ViewController:UITextFieldDelegate {

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

  if textField.tag == 101 {
    // first textField
  } else if textField.tag == 102 {
    // second textField
  } else {
   // else
  }
 }
}
```